# measure of quantity: a hundred of bricks

Tags: numbers, dictionaries, measuring-units

According to the entry of "hundred" in the OED

> Only in measures of quantity, the structure is **a hundred of
>   bricks**.

What does **measure of quantity** mean here, especially as opposed to *a hundred bricks*?

Comment: I have never seen such a sentence, but I have seen Q: "How many bricks?" A: "A hundred of them."

Comment: Because a hundred of bricks is old style.

Comment: The entry in the OED actually says "b. not a hundred miles from; within a hundred miles of: near, close to, in or at; also figurative; (all the same in) a hundred years (hence) (and similar expressions): gnomic formulas of consolation for present adversity; a hundred of bricks: **see brick n.1 and adj.1**";  I suggest you do "**see brick n.1 and adj.1**"

Comment: @Greybeard I am consulting OED 4.0. Can you post a snap of the page you're looking up? thanks

Comment: It is beyond me to put an image into a comment. The reference is under "Brick" noun at P3.b. (Online version) Originally U.S. like a thousand (also hundred) of brick(s) and variants: ... very violently or severely. ...to punish or reprimand (someone) severely. Now rare....replaced by to come down on like a ton of bricks: 1969  "*Because of my debt to Fussell, I have no desire to fall upon him like ‘a hundred of bricks*’.  c. [a ton of bricks]: to attack or punish with great vigour; to reprimand severely.1938  "*If there's any fighting I shall come down like a ton of bricks on both of you*."

Comment: @Greybeard can you upload the image to https://pasteboard.co/ and paste here the link in this comment section? thanks

Comment: See https://pasteboard.co/IYTwrd4.jpg

Comment: @Greybeard the one is want is the entry of **hundred**

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/IYTGA6T.jpg

https://pasteboard.co/IYTGZbi.jpg

Comment: @Greybeard It's the same as I have. Why did you mentioned it then?

Comment: @GJC because you asked for an image and then asked for more. You also read that "a hundred of bricks" was rare (and thus, irrelevant).. You also read "a hundred years" and "a hundred miles" both of which are measures of quantity. "What quantity of miles?" "A hundred miles."